# Real Time Data Visualization example

Tags: performance, opengl, graphics, real-time, visualization

I am working on realtime data visualization project and need to rendering raw data with performance up to ~10Gb/sec.

Requirements are to be able to show up to 10000 data tracks as strips represented by max/min value (signal and noise range) for each X coordinate. Displaying of data should be smooth and take not more than 20% of single cpu core. Strips are overlap and should use some color mix technic. System is Linux and interface c++. Calculations gave me 10000strips x 1000points/0.01sec to display*2points min/max => data rate 2*10^9 points per sec or about 8Gb/sec (about throughput of pcie3.0 x8).

I have very limited experience with graphics. I'm looking for same examples how to:
1) Pass data to video card with rate 8Gb/sec
2) Fill rectangle on video card with some stats like number of strips passing each point (or do this step on cpu to save pcie throughput?)
3) Translate stats from (2) into point color and display this rectangle

I looked into OpenGL but it looks overkill for pure 2D. What technology I can use for this project? Or are any examples I can start with? Also I need to use free library/api for linux only.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately questions like these are [too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), please try to reduce the scope of your question, and ask [minimal specific programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Pardon my hint/question - where did you get display able to show 10 000 data strips (each at least 50px tall?) with 1000 points each at once .. and a human operator able to watch them all at 100fps?

Comment: Data strips may overlap. With proper color coding tool should allow to visually estimate outliers, data density and may be some flow partitioning and partition stream behavior. With overlap it does not need to have thousands of pictures resolution. Regular display should be enough.

Comment: I'm asking for 100fps to be able to reserve 70% of cpu core performance for data preparation with 30fps

Answer (score 1):

Okay, 10Gbit/s of data is about 1GB (gigabyte) of data per second. That's about 20MB of data per display update interval (I'm just doing back of the envelope estimations here). Considering R8G8B8 colorspace that'd be about uncompressed 4k video.

No idea how to make linear plotted data tracks out of this, without having to seriously rewire the human visual cortex first. Maybe invest into gene editing first?

Joking aside, what you're asking about, *technically* is perfectly possible. First things first one important note about this remark:

> I looked into OpenGL but it looks overkill for pure 2D.

*pshht* I let you in, into a little secret: OpenGL **is** a 2D graphics API. All that 3 and 4 element vectors, matrices, the talk about transforms and stuff? All "smoke and mirrors" so to speak. All this "3D" stuff is actually just some convenience operations to make it easier to calculate, where on a flat screen a projection of a higher dimensional objects is ending up in 2D space.

All the actual drawing? It all happens in 2D.

> What technology I can use for this project?

OpenGL, or Vulkan, or DirectX, or any other accelerated graphics API.

> Calculations gave me 10000strips x 1000points

Okay, now you have to find a display with at least 2*10000 pixels in at least one direction (why 2× ?  Because Nyquist, i.e. the Sampling Theorem). But once you've got that, you're golden. Maybe put a bunch of 4k displays into a video wall, and create a beefy multi monitor setup.

To get the data to the GPU you want to avoid unnecessary overhead where possible.

The general idea is to create some buffers on the GPU which you stream the data to in a round-robin fashion. With OpenGL you do this through buffer objects (glGenBuffers, glBindBuffer, glBufferData, glBufferSubData).

Unfortuately current graphics APIs all are kind of "locked on" to do everything through memory mappings. Yes, I get it, doing things through virtual memory feels nice. But it involves populating page tables, which is expensive. As counterintuitive as may sound, a directed I/O write (via DMA) often is cheaper, than going through virtual memory mappings.

But we don't get to choose how it's done. In OpenGL there's the function glBufferSubData which *may* operate through a directed I/O write, but often enough it does a page mapping dance behind the scenes. With glMapBuffer this becomes explicit.

In Vulkan everything happens through mapped buffers, so there's that.

Once you've got the data on the GPU you write some shader code, that takes the data from the buffer objects and uses it to control the generation of "pixels" (well, fragments actually, but that's just almost the same thing). As surprising it may be, drawing a full-screen triangle (clipped using the scissor test) and reading from the buffers on a per-pixel base in the fragment shader often outperforms generation of individual line segments on modern hardware.

Here's a rough outline what you need to do:

- (optional, but recommended) Find a display with high enough resolution to actually being able to show what you want to see.
- (optional) Genetically engineer humans so that their eyes are actually able to resolve that amount of detail.
- Get your grips on OpenGL. Write some "Hello Triangle" program.
- Learn how to read data from buffer objects in the various shader stages.
- Learn how to create line segments from buffer data in a vertex shader (don't bother with geometry shaders, they're awful).
- Learn how to use distance field tests to generate plots from a fragment shader (i.e. for each fragment (roughly a pixel)) test how far it is from the plot line to be, and color it accordingly - this gives really high quality plots with very smooth lines, often at better performance than a line strip.

Comment: nice answer btw. if the wanted output is just **bin aligned** oscillogram than the x resolution does not need to be doubled also alternating colors may be used instead of doubling the resolution to emphasize individual stripes.